# Greiner´s Field Quantization question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, wick-theorem

[image: Greiner, Field Quantization, page 245 (Moller Scattering)]

I  upload a screenshot of Greiner´s book on QFT. I don´t understand one step. I need help understanding equation (3), what are the mathematical steps in between?
Greiner, *Field Quantization*, page 245 (Moller Scattering)

Comment: Please use MathJax instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the commutation relations (assuming bosons) $[b_{\mathbf p,s},b^\dagger_{\mathbf p's'}]=\delta(\mathbf p-\mathbf p')\delta_{ss'}$ to get rid of the operators.

So if you have
$$A=\langle 0|b_{\mathbf p's'}b^\dagger_{\mathbf p's'}|0\rangle$$
then
$$A=\langle 0|b^\dagger_{\mathbf p's'}b_{ \mathbf p's'}+\delta(\mathbf p-\mathbf p')\delta_{ss'}|0\rangle$$
but then the operators in the left side are 0 because $b_{\mathbf ps}|0\rangle=0$. Using $\langle 0|0\rangle=1$, we finally have
$$A=\delta(\mathbf p-\mathbf p')\delta_{ss'}$$.

Advanced techniques include the use of [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem).

Comment: So basically I need to bring all b daggers to the left and b to the right applying that rule many times? to get something like <0|b^dagger b^dagger b^dagger...b b b |0>

Comment: @IgnacioAnesini yes, but notice that if you bring any b to the right or $b^\dagger$ to the left, it already becomes 0 so you can simplify most of the moves

Comment: Thank you for the help